# How to define REST API endpoints?

Tags: rest

A REST API performs two functions: gets documents and creates documents.

Initially I thought the endpoints should be:

```
GET https://[main link]/api/documents/ < gets documents  
POST https://[main link]/api/documents/ < creates a document
```

The problem is that the GET request will also contain a request body, because the searches performed can be very complex. So both requests should be POST. But then they become identical. How to differentiate between them? Would doing this be appropriate or not?

```
POST https://[main link]/api/documents/search < gets documents  
POST https://[main link]/api/documents/create < creates a document
```

Comment: if I get you right you want to send search parameters alongside your get request?

Comment: @Fabus yes, all the search parameters are going to be sent as json in a request body, nothing will be in the uri

Comment: sending search parameters in a JSON body alongside a GET request is unconventional. Typically, GET requests are used to retrieve data and don't have a request body. Instead, parameters are usually sent as query parameters in the URL. In case you explicitly want to avoid the params being visible in the URL you could do it as you described.

Comment: And what’s stopping you from having a POST endpoint that acts as a GET endpoint? It’s a frequent use case to have request body so large GET can’t handle it.

Comment: "Would doing this be appropriate or not?" - that's up to you. If your application works this way, why not use this approach?

Comment: "The problem is that the GET request will also contain a request body" — **This is a really bad idea** — The HTTP specification does not allow GET requests to have a body (it doesn't forbid them, but it does say the behaviour is undefined). Many HTTP clients (including the `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` implementations in browsers) **will not allow** GET requests to have a body.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actual question is here. Are you asking for opinions on the best way to name end points? Are you asking for opinions on the best way to document your API? (It really looks like you are asking for opinions, which is a form of question not allowed here).

Comment: Design Patterns, usage of HTTP Verbs, Various Schema recommendations for REST, GraphQL, Code Styleguides... You TAKE the recommendations when possible and BREAK them when necessary ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You can create and define different REST endpoints for different functions when you are developing a RESTful application. The exact method to create and define REST API endpoints are dependant on Languages and Frameworks used.

The python flask code to do the same is as follows (You can replicate the same in other languages/frameworks as well)

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/apis/documents/search',methods=['POST'])
def search():
    #Code for search function (Code to get document)
@app.route('/apis/documents/create',methods=['POST'])
def search():
    #Code for create function (Code to create document)
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This essentially creates two rest endpoints as asked in the question

```
POST https://[main link]/api/documents/search < gets documents  
POST https://[main link]/api/documents/create < creates a document
```

Hope this helps.